# I have created a Maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have below jar files: **sl4j-log4j12-1.7.25** but while executing i am getting the below error:
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6.99 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6] 
SLF4J: See [here](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch) for further details.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
>     at
>   org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.info(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:346)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your slf4j-api version is the same as your slf4j-log version.

Your answer is in the link you provided!

> **slf4j-api version does not match that of the binding**
>
> An SLF4J binding designates an artifact such as slf4j-jdk14.jar or slf4j-> > log4j12.jar used to bind slf4j to an underlying logging framework, say, java.util.logging and respectively log4j.
>   Mixing mixing different versions of slf4j-api.jar and SLF4J binding can cause problems. For example, if you are using slf4j-api-1.8.0-alpha2.jar, then you should also use slf4j-simple-1.8.0-alpha2.jar, using slf4j-simple-1.5.5.jar will not work.
>
> NOTE From the client's perspective all versions of slf4j-api are compatible. Client code compiled with slf4j-api-N.jar will run perfectly fine with slf4j-api-M.jar for any N and M. You only need to ensure that the version of your binding matches that of the slf4j-api.jar. You do not have to worry about the version of slf4j-api.jar used by a given dependency in your project. You can always use any version of slf4j-api.jar, and as long as the version of slf4j-api.jar and its binding match, you should be fine.
>   At initialization time, if SLF4J suspects that there may be a api vs. binding version mismatch problem, it will emit a warning about the suspected mismatch.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. I have added the same slf4j-api version as  slf4j-log version. But while executing got the below error:

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. I have added the same slf4j-api version as  slf4j-log version. But Igot the below error:   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/tcsalku/Downloads/cmdChatbot/cmdChatbot/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.alicebot.ab.Bot).